# Can't get Steam to launch on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: steam, 20.10

Fairly new Ubuntu user here, and I can't seem to get steam to launch. I had no issues with it when I used 20.04 a while ago, but I can't get it running at all on 20.10.

When launching through the command line, the output I get is

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/adnonnymous/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2020-12-29 23:56:58] Startup - updater built Dec 20 2020 23:07:02
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1608507519)
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

And then the terminal hangs. I've tried googling this, and none of the solutions have given any success. I've rebooted, I've reinstalled, I ran `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`, and nothing.

Comment: You did a search for your error? SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Comment: Yes, and I tried the results I got from that to no avail. I ended up getting it working, but I'm not really sure how. I installed a different graphics driver hoping that would fix the issue, but all it did was break my cursor lmao. So I thought I reinstalled the driver I had before, but think I must've installed a different one, because it works fine now.